# Function works until called with an ipywidgets event

Tags: python, function, python-requests, ipywidgets

I have been working on this for who knows how long but I have two functions: one that is activated through ipywidgets special event and the next that is called within the first function.

function number one:

```
def lipas_button_clicked(b):
    '''
    Def used to select and fetch dataframe from LIPAS
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    PARAMETERS
    - b <button default>

    RETURNS
    - Automatic append of selected YKR IDs <list element> (global variable)
    - Message in display
    '''
    code = str(select_lipas.value)

    lipas = GetLipasData(code)

    return print(lipas)
```

function number two:

```
def GetLipasData(typecode):

    code_list = [typecode]

    lipas = pd.DataFrame()

    for x in code_list:

        typecode = x
        r = requests.get("""http://lipas.cc.jyu.fi/api/sports-places?fields=type.name&fields=location.sportsPlaces&fields=location.geometries&fields=name&fields=type.typeCode&fields=location.locationId&fields=location.city.name&fields=location.postalCode&fields=location.address&typeCodes=""" + typecode + """&cityCodes=91""").json()

        df = pd.json_normalize(r, record_path=['location', 'geometries', 'features'], meta=[['location', 'sportsPlaces'], ['location', 'address'], ['location', 'postalCode'], ['name']])

        df['typeCode'] = typecode

        lipas = lipas.append(df)

    return lipas
```

Whenever I run this code using the widgets button the first function returns an empty dataframe to me. However, when I call the second function like this:

```
# example typecode 
temp = '1120'

lipas = GetLipasData(temp)

print(lipas)
```

The function works and I end up with the desired dataframe. Here is a snippet of the dataframe:

```
      type geometry.type                  geometry.coordinates  \
0  Feature         Point  [25.0014104043243, 60.1858473428042]   
1  Feature         Point  [25.0191651714749, 60.2636222119604]   
2  Feature         Point  [25.0908944598678, 60.2191648730633]   
3  Feature         Point  [24.9503407234607, 60.1634158059106]   
4  Feature         Point   [24.9437999467401, 60.162526333009]   

   properties.pointId location.sportsPlaces  location.address  \
0              577095              [603807]  Ståhlbergintie 2   
1              577194              [520138]         Rajatie 7   
2              577098               [85737]  Kukkaniityntie 2   
3               73310               [82865]     Unioninkatu 2   
4              577037              [603746]        Ratakatu 6   

  location.postalCode                                          name typeCode  
0               00570   Brändö lågstadieskolan / Lähiliikuntapaikka     1120  
1               00730   Hiidenkiven peruskoulu / Lähiliikuntapaikka     1120  
2               00900         Botby grundskola / Lähiliikuntapaikka     1120  
3               00130       Grundskolan Norsen / Lähiliikuntapaikka     1120  
4               00120  Helsingin normaalilyseo / Lähiliikuntapaikka     1120
```

I cannot for the life of me understand why calling the same function through the ipywidgets event does not work. Here is the code for the ipywidgets.

```
# adding the Select widget. Select means that you can select the correct one.
select_lipas = widgets.Select(placeholder='Valitse palvelu(t)', 
                             options=lipas_options,
                             layout = {'width':'max-content'},
                             ensure_option=True, 
                             disabled=False)

# adding the button widget. Click Me Tooltip is an action which run after clicking on the button.
b = widgets.Button(description='Valitse LIPAS palvelu', 
                   disabled=False, 
                   button_style='info', 
                   tooltip='Click me', 
                   icon='check')

# adding the click event to the button. To add event you do it as a function
b.on_click(lipas_button_clicked)
```

Any ideas? Please let me know if more information is required. Much appreciated for any help in advance!

UPDATE:
I was using AppLayout() to display my widgets and for whatever reason this was not sending the selected code back to my functions. I tested it out by switching back to displaying each widget separately and it worked immediately. Any ideas on the difference?

Comment: I suspect that the line 'code = str(select_lipas.value)' is returning an empty string

Comment: I checked for that but when I add a print(code) line in the first function it returns me the typecode that I select with ipywidgets, so that part seems to work

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical problem with `on_click`.

You are returning an object at the end of the function, but it is not possible to assign it to a variable in the main namespace. You need the `lipas_button_clicked` function to have a side effect, not return a value.

One way around this is to create a `global` variable, and within your `lipas_button_clicked` function, instead of returning the data from your `GetLipasData` function, assign it to that global variable. It will then be accessible from outside your `lipas_button_clicked` function.

Comment: Yea that is true and would be useful if I needed the dataframe. My actual desired result isn't to save the dataframe. With this code I was actually trying to problem solve another issue that has been arising within the second function, that is not fully posted here. While your solution would be useful for saving the dataframe, the return in lipas_button_clicked still shows me the dataframe printed out, just as: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [typeCode]
Index: []

Comment: I did test it out and made lipas a global variable, but it still does not return anything other than an empty dataframe

Comment: Hi! I have an update on my code. I was using AppLayout() to display my widgets and for whatever reason this was not sending the selected code back to my functions. I tested it out by switching back to displaying each widget separately and it worked immediately. Any ideas on why that is?